# Как выделить элемента ListBox, при нажатии на его содержимое?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, toggle

У меня есть ListBox в который подгружаются Employees и ListBox заполняется элементами в которых внутри ToggleButton. При выделении элемента выбирается employee, при нажатии на ToggleButton открывается боковое меню для этого employee. Проблема в том что при нажатии на ToggleButton не срабатывает выделение элемента ListBox. А хотелось бы, что бы за один клик выбирался employee и открывалась боковое меню. Как лучше это сделать?

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Width="400"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployee}">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                      Width="300" 
                                      Margin="5"
                                      Content="{Binding Path=FIO}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, ElementName=DrawerRight}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**При нажатии на элемент ListBox:**
[image: При нажатии на элемент ListBox]

**При нажатии на ToggleButton:**
[image: При нажатии на ToggleButton]

**При нажатии на ToggleButton без предварительного нажатия на элемент ListBox**
[image: При нажатии на ToggleButton без предварительного нажатия на элемент ListBox]

Comment: А вам не кажется, что вы делаете нечто странное? Вы используете два контрола, которые предназначены под задачи выбора, вопрос только зачем? Хотите `ListBox` - пожалуйста, используйте его с нужным вам стилем. Хотите `ToggleButton` - без проблем, берите `ItemsControl`, привязывайте, получайте кликабельные кнопки, без лишнего выделения от `ListBox`. Не, ну если хотите все разом, то сделайте триггер, по которому вы будете проверять `IsSelected` объекта `ListBox`'a и на его основе менять вид. Либо делайте в VM слое свойство, к которому привяжете все это.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да, уверен что это странно. Просто не знаю как написать такой стиль, который решил бы мою проблему. Пытался искать как писать стили, все что нахожу это как писать стили меняющие, дефолтные свойства контрола. Может есть какой-то хороший гайд, пример?

Comment: @Максим при чем тут стиль? Просто замените ListBox на ItemsControl, если надо, то заверните его в ScrollViewer, а ScrollViewer в Border, чтобы рамочку нарисовать, и дело с концом.

Comment: Примерно [такое](https://pastebin.com/niJ1EZLa) решение вашей задачи, если нужны именно `ToggleButton`. Будет список кнопочек с именами, где каждая кнопочка "западает" при клике и возвращается в исходное положение при клике на другую кнопку. Но это мы, по сути, продублировали поведение `ListBox`, с его выделением. Так может вам просто взять `ListBox`, без кнопок и пользоваться им? Я просто не до конца понимаю вашу проблему и вашу задачу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, задача заключается в том что бы по нажатию на элемент открывалось боковое меню и там отображалась имя как на нажатой кнопке. Используя ListBox и ToggleButton у меня получилось это сделать, но это "странное" решение.

Comment: Это не объясняет того, почему вы просто не используете `ListBox` с его `SelectedItem`, в `set` которого можно поместить вызов метода показа меню. Зачем `ToggleButton` то?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ. Да, я хотел использовать ListBox, но не смог открыть боковое меню из ListBox. В ToggleButton открытие бокового меню было в `IsChecked`. Можно пожалуйста подробнее, что такое `set`?

Comment: Ну вы пишете по правилам MVVM, а значит у вас все на привязках, а привязки доступны **только** к публичным свойствам, а свойства, это `public type Name {get; set;}`, вот `get;` и `set;` это грубо говоря методы, которые выполняются в момент `get` - чтения значения, `set` - изменения значения. Ну вот вы и можете раскрыть нужный вам блок и прописать там вызов своей логике (`private int _val; public int Value get => _val; set { _val = value; SomeMethod(); }`). Вот на этой основе и делайте привязку к `SelectedItem` и в его `set` логику открытия меню.